# How to properly handle dynamic allocation for an array of strings?

Tags: c, string, malloc, free

I want to make an array of string, the array is of a fixed maximum size and likewise for the strings it holds.
Here I initialize the array.

```
 char* students_names[MAX_STUDENTS] = {NULL};
```

And here I am allocating the memory needed for each name:

```
void init_db(int students_info[][INFO], char* students_names[], int n){
    int sizeOfChar = sizeof(char);
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        students_info[i][0] = -1;
        students_info[i][1] = -1;

        students_names[i] = "\0";
        students_names[i] = malloc(sizeOfChar*(MAX_NAME+1));
    }
}
```

I actually don't know why this line: `students_names[i] = "\0";` should come before this one:
`students_names[i] = malloc(sizeOfChar*(MAX_NAME+1));` but for some reason it doesn't work any other way. I know that `"\0"` signifies the end of the String.

A function for deallocating the memory:

```
void clean_db(char* students_names[], int n){
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        free(students_names[i]);
    }
    printf("All %d entries were deleted!!!\n", n);
}
```

The program seems to work fine on Clion (simply printing, deleting and adding information to the array from a user input\file) but my assignment is being tested on CodeBlocks, and on it I get the following exceptions on separate tests:

```
double free or corruption (out): 0x00007ffc12dc7bc0 ***
free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000400c94 ***
```

I tried and I couldn't figure out is the cause so I guess there's something fundamental that I don't understand here. The way I see it:

`students_names[i]` is a pointer to the initial position in the char array of the `i`'th student, and when I assign it with `malloc` I assign the length of this array. When I use `scanf("%s", students_names[i])` I assign an input string starting from this pointer in memory, and when I use `free(students_names[i])` I dellocate the memory and the pointer will essentially hold a garbage value.

If anyone could shed some light on what I'm getting wrong that would be great.

EDIT:
Alright, I'm fairly new to C (obvious) so perhaps I underestimated how complex the debugging is in comparison to what I know. Anyway, here is all the code that has a chance of being relevant to the issue I described:

```
/* main Function */
int main()
{
    int students_info[MAX_STUDENTS][INFO];
    char* students_names[MAX_STUDENTS] = {NULL};
    init_db(students_info, students_names,MAX_STUDENTS);
    int op = INIT;
    while (scanf("%d", &op)!= 0)

    {

        switch(op){
            case INIT: if (read_students_info(students_info, students_names,MAX_STUDENTS )!= SUCCESS){return FAILURE;} break;
            case ADD: add_student(students_info, students_names,MAX_STUDENTS); break;
            case DEL: delete_student(students_info, students_names,MAX_STUDENTS); break;
            default: break;
        }
    }
    clean_db(students_names,MAX_STUDENTS);

    return 0;
}

void init_db(int students_info[][INFO], char* students_names[], int n){
    int sizeOfChar = sizeof(char);
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        students_info[i][0] = -1;
        students_info[i][1] = -1;

        students_names[i] = malloc(sizeOfChar*(MAX_NAME+1));
    }
}

int read_students_info(int students_info[][INFO], char* students_names[], int n){
    int M;
    scanf("%d", &M);
    if(M > n){
        printTooManyStudentsError();
        return FAILURE;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<M; i++){
        scanf("%s %d %d", students_names[i], &students_info[i][0], &students_info[i][1]);
    }
    printWriteToDatabaseSuccess(M);
    return SUCCESS;
}

void add_student(int students_info[][INFO], char* students_names[], int n){
    int id, minutes;
    char studentName[MAX_NAME];
    scanf("%s %d %d", studentName, &id, &minutes);
    if(doesExist(id, students_info, n)){
        printStudentExists(id);
        return;
    }

    if(!addNewStudent(studentName, id, minutes, students_names, students_info, n)){
        printClassIsFull(id);
    }
}

bool addNewStudent(char studentName[MAX_NAME], int id, int minutes, char* students_names[],
                   int students_info[][INFO], int n){
    int emptyIndex = -1;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(students_info[i][0] != -1)
            continue;
        emptyIndex = i;
        break;
    }
    if(emptyIndex == -1){
        return false;
    }
    students_names[emptyIndex] = studentName;
    students_info[emptyIndex][0] = id;
    students_info[emptyIndex][1] = minutes;
    printStudentAddedSuccessfully(id);
    return true;
}

int doesExist(int id, int students_info[][INFO], int n){
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(students_info[i][0] == id){
            return i+1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void delete_student(int students_info[][INFO], char* students_names[],int n){
    int id, index;
    scanf("%d", &id);
    index = doesExist(id, students_info, n);
    if(!index){
        printStudentDoesNotExist(id);
        return;
    }
    students_info[index-1][0] = -1;
    students_info[index-1][1] = -1;
    students_names[index] = "\0";
    printDeletedSuccessfully(id);
}

void clean_db(char* students_names[], int n){
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(students_names[i] != NULL)
            free(students_names[i]);
    }
    printf("All %d entries were deleted!!!\n", n);
}
```

Comment: *"I actually don't know why this line: `students_names[i] = "\0"`"* - neither does anyone else. It's nonsense. That line of code is a recipe for problems regardless, as it sets the base address of a string literal (e.g. read-only string) in to a hot non-const pointer. Whoever wrote that is either misguided or misinformed.

Comment: You've shown code for allocating and freeing the memory, that code is fine (apart from `students_names[i] = "\0";` which is completely unnecessary). The problem you have is somewhere else.

Comment: You description 'the way I see it' is also perfectly correct. I guess the thing you don;t realise is that any line (or multiple lines) of your code could be causing the memory corruption, but the problem is not *detected* until later when you try to free the memory. So don't (necessarily) look just at the allocation and freeing of memory, the problem could be anywhere in your code.

Comment: I figured this line makes no sense, but I'm confused as to why it wouldn't work without it. I'll post the rest of the code, maybe it's necessary to understand the issue. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @user3917631 Because when you have a program with an error, random nonsense happens. That's the nature of C. Bad programs don't behave in a predictable manner, only bug free programs are predictable.

Comment: @user3917631 You maybe starting to realise that debugging C programs is hard.

Comment: You could try to set students_names[i] to NULL after freeing and see if it makes a difference in the error you get.

Comment: Without knowing how the functions shown are called, nor how the variables being passed in are initialised any answer would not be more then a guess.

Comment: Why wouldn't you start with `struct student { int info; char *name; };`? `here is all the code` So.. where are `#include`s? Or did you use none?

Comment: @john Yes exactly that. I edited the post with the entirety of the code that can be relevant to the issue, perhaps you could spot something that could lead to the crash?

Comment: @KamilCuk I posted only snippets of code. I also have includes and function for printing messages but I think it will only add noise because those cannot be related to the problem. Also I don't use struct because I can only use what we've been taught in the university so far.

Comment: @user3121023 oh, that makes sense. How do I deal with assigning input string into the variable then?

Comment: @user3917631 Just read the input directly into the memory you allocated earlier. `scanf(..., students_names[empty_index], ...);` Some reorganization of the code required but that is how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

You could allocate the memory in a single step. If you want the memory on the stack :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_STUDENTS 32
#define MAX_NAME 64

int main() {
    char students_names[MAX_STUDENTS][MAX_NAME] = {0};

    strcpy(students_names[0], "Charles"); // thanks to @n. 'pronouns' m
    strcpy(students_names[1], "Emily");
    strcpy(students_names[2], "John");
    int i=0;
    while (students_names[i][0]) printf("%s\n", students_names[i++]);
    return 0;
}
```

Or on the heap (the deallocation is done in a single step too) :

```
int main() {
    char (*students_names)[MAX_STUDENTS][MAX_NAME] = malloc(sizeof(*students_names));
    memset(*students_names, 0, sizeof(*students_names));

    strcpy((*students_names)[0], "Charles");
    strcpy((*students_names)[1], "Emily");
    strcpy((*students_names)[2], "John");
    int i=0;
    while ((*students_names)[i][0]) printf("%s\n", (*students_names)[i++]);
    free(*students_names);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `memcpy(students_names[0], "Charles", sizeof("Charles")+1);` This is undefined behaviour. `sizeof("Charles")` is `strlen("Charles")+1`, so your other `+1` makes `memcpy` go over the array boundary. Please just use `strcpy`.

Comment: You're right, it's a lot better. Thanks !

Comment: Also `*students_names[1]` needs to be `(*students_names)[1]`

Comment: I wasn't sure about that, thanks again  !

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, I would say that `student_info` and `students_names` are possibly close together, and you are running out of bounds on `student_info` and messing up the pointers in `student_names`.  Why does it work on Clion?  It may be artificially spacing the variables out so you have some padding in between, but the other environment is not doing that.

Answer (score 0):

From the error I can estimate that you pass a value that exceeds the bound of the array of pointers. Thus your program attempts to free a location that is not a char*. If my estimation is true, then fixing the code as below may solve your problem.

```
void clean_db(char* students_names[], int n){
    if(n >= MAX_STUDENTS) {
        printf("The number of items to delete is out of boundary\n);
        return; // Simply don't proceed
    }
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        free(students_names[i]);
    }
    printf("All %d entries were deleted!!!\n", n);
}
```